# Change ASP.NET MVC default looking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am follow [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Live-Demo-5b56ca3a) article and `ASP.NET` learning site in order to build simple web site. i have database with an objects, each object represent file on dist and several properties (size, name etc...) and i have a question:

After add the controller like in this article (min 1:45) and run my application it navigate into my files page:

[image]

And to my file details:

[image]

How hard is (i am not new developer but totally new in websites) to change this 2 pages (default looking) to something else / other design ? (i follow ASP.NET learning site guides but sometimes is hard to implement it alone i i want something else)

BTW, i will glad for some screenshots\examples\tutorials  for new look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the project there is a Content folder, you will find you CSS and image files etc. in here. Your Views folder contains the html and razor view engine. If you are not aware of how to change the structure and look of a website I recommend you start the tutorials here

```
http://www.w3schools.com/
```

And for further asp.net mvc help here

```
http://www.asp.net/mvc
```

Comment: How can i see the design of my files page (not home page) ?

Comment: You need to complete the tutorials in the links above. Your html will be found within the Views folder. There should be a folder in there with a name which corresponds to you Controller name, so if your controller is called FilesController the folder within the Views folder with the corresponding views will be called Files. You really need to start at the start, with the tutorials above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio, you might try the asp.net mvc template to start a new website project, it has initial design which might be good foundation to start and afterwards you need to change css files to get what you need.

Comment: I am using the asp.net mvc